# Who are these guys?

Tags: discussion, captcha

[image]

I was giving an answer and this page showing up! I am wondering, who are these guys? **(human robots)**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_Conchords

Comment: You could of [googled it](https://images.google.com/imghp?hl=en&gws_rd=ssl) *(couldn't post the link as the URL was too long, just click the camera copy the image url and bingo)* or just clicked on the image.

Comment: Personally, I think they should be replaced with this bot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwXR-gey9XE (nsfw)

Comment: Those are robots.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I don't think they are. I think they're human and the picture is a joke. (Yes, I'm pulling your leg, hehe.)

Comment: That's something it's been hunting me for years, thanks for solving this riddle.

Comment: binary solo! 0000000000000010000000100101001010

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11319/who-are-the-robots-in-the-captcha-request (July 2009) -- top Google hit for ["meta robots captcha"](https://www.google.com/search?q=meta+robots+captcha)

Comment: +61 really!!!! ?....

Comment: @SaiRamSudheer: so? A lot of people must've been curious about this, plus it appeared in the Community Bulletin sidebar on the main site a couple of times.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it is a duplicate question and it took 5 secs to get the answer using image search ..

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You are looking at a scene from the comedy series [Flight of the Conchords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_Conchords), from the pilot episode, titled [*Sally*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sally_%28Flight_of_the_Conchords%29#.22Robots.22). [Jeff Atwood is a fan](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/podcast-12/).

You can see that scene online: [Robot Song music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvrva8NoMLM). The video is even *linked from the image*.

Comment: OK guys, band meeting...

Answer (score 15):

A Google image search yields the answer: they're from a comedy show named ["Flight of the Conchords"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_Conchords_%28TV_series%29).